# Code coverage for Developer pod unit tests

Tags: xcode, unit-testing, cocoapods

Right now I'm unit testing my Developer CocoaPods which is working fine. Tests are running and working inside the Example project.

However, the code coverage only takes coverage of the project files, not the Developer pod files:

[image]

I'm looking for a way to give feedback about the pod code coverage. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Dummy guide for @teriiehina's answer.

1. Go to Product -> Scheme -> Edit Scheme...
2. Click `Test`
3. Enable code coverage for the Example project

[image: enable code coverage]

4. Click `Build`
5. Click `+` in the lower-left corner. Select the development pod target

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This problem is known and a solution is given on [Cocoapod's github](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/3706).

The solution should be to enable code coverage on the library as well. But this doesn't work for my new pod. However, testing the library by adding the test target to its "Test" actions does work. But I also see coverage for others pods, which is not what I want.

Also, we have another project which, by running tests on the demo app's scheme, shows the code coverage for the pod's files, as expected. Can't find the differences between the two projects.

So this is a "search in progress" bug.

Update: [this answer](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/3706#issuecomment-143806128) worked for me.